# A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7, django-models

I am developing a web-app in Django (python). It was working fine in last few days, but then i started developing another app using django. Now after switching to that old app development when I am running the server, I am getting an error: "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

**The traceback from the terminal:**

```
File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 44, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named security
```

**Settings file:**

```
"""
Django settings for SteanneWebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^ay$t!hm-4fm4!)ppxoc!$j1^p1b&kiv+*s&3eox^k*bh$er^8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'News',
    'Messages',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SteanneWebsite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SteanneWebsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#Template Location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SecurityMiddleware is new in the Django development version, and is not available in the released 1.7. If you really want to use it, you should switch to development head, but I do not recommend running a production site from dev. You should probably just remove the reference to it in the middleware settings.

Comment: I commented 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', but it is still giving me the same message.... Traceback after commenting:
Traceback (most recent call last):(few other traces as shown above and few more new ones)
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 168, in __call__
        self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/somdipdey/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 46, in load_middleware
        mw_instance = mw_class()
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Sounds like a different problem, you should show (by editing your question) what your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES looks like now.

Comment: Actually, argh, what is django.contrib.admin doing in middleware_classes?

Comment: yeah. sorry....to fix this problem i added 'django.contrib.admin' in middleware_classes as shown in another debug article. but yeah, after deleting it, the website is working fine now. Thank you Daniel.